# Jdbctemplate queryforObject: EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

Tags: spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am calling below method by passing value to a.

```java
public Sample get(String a) {
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL, new Object[] { a }, rowMapper);
}
```

On execute of the below queryForObject method, it throws exception

> "EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, 
>   actual 0" and object array value be null.
>       public  T queryForObject(String sql, Object[] args, RowMapper rowMapper) throws DataAccessException {
>             List results = query(sql, args, new RowMapperResultSetExtractor(rowMapper, 1));
>             return DataAccessUtils.requiredSingleResult(results);
>         }

Answer (score 4):

Your query didn't return a result.

Two solutions :

- fix your query to always return a result
- try/catch EmptyResultDataAccessException and choose the appropriate behavior

Comment: Or use https://stackoverflow.com/a/51318368/4179032

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify more, by my recent experience -> it clearly mentions:
"EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0" which means it is expecting only 1 row, as a result of your SQL query execution, not 0 and not more than 1. So, make sure execution of your SQL query results in only one row.