# How to handle jdbc.queryForObject if it doesn't return a row

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I would like to know how to properly use jdbc in my case.

The `saveLinkHistory` column is a bit(1) type in mysql.

```
public boolean getIsSavedLinkHistory(String name) {
        String sql = "select saveLinkHistory from users where name = ?";
        Boolean isTracked = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] { name }, Boolean.class);
        return isTracked;
}
```

The query worked well until I got an error of `Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0` because sometimes the `name` didn't exist, the `queryForObject` method expects that I ALWAYS get 1 row as a result.

How can I handle this case, just throw an exception that says "name" doesn't exist ? 
and by the way, is `Boolean` ok here ? because I didn't see such code before.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
return DataAccessUtils.singleResult(jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new SingleColumnRowMapper<Boolean>(), param1, param2));
```

Answer (score 7):

queryForObject method of JdbcTemplate expects that your query should return one row always else it will throw EmptyResultDataAccessException. 
You can simply use query method with ResultSetExtractor instead of queryForObject. ResultSetExtractor - extractData(ResultSet rs) method would return an arbitrary result object, or null if no data returned. You can throw your relevant exception if it returns null.

```
 return jdbc.query(sql, new ResultSetExtractor<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
                                                   DataAccessException {
        return rs.next() ? rs.getBoolean("column_name") : null;
    }
});
```