# Query with no results JDBCTemplate

Tags: java, spring, exception, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have my method:

```
public boolean validar(String login, String password) {     

        return !jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from usuarios where login = ?", 
                new Object[] { login }, Usuarios.class).equals(0);
}
```

it works normally, but if I don't have a result it appears this joptionpane:

[image]

I searched but found nothing about
it is possible to do a treatment
in case there is no result with this login / password
show example:

there is no such login /

Comment: *"and i got this error:"* Don't post images of text, post the **text** itself as an [edit]! Further, always call `exception.printStackTrace()` on exceptions, unless logging them, in addition to whatever else is done with them. General tips: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle jdbc.queryForObject if it doesn't return a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066254/how-to-handle-jdbc-queryforobject-if-it-doesnt-return-a-row)

Answer (score 4):

As [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/queryforobject-throws-emptyresultdataaccessexception-when-record-not-found/) suggest, catch exception and return false

```
} catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: try {
  return !jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from usuarios where login = ?", 
    new Object[] { login }, Usuarios.class).equals(0);
  } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
      return false;
  }